# Phonegap facebook plugin not working with native facebook app on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I am trying to create a simple login with facebook feature on my phonegap app. I'm using Android 4.3, cordova 2.7 and the official phonegap plugin: https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin

I'm trying to get the Simple example working provided in the example folder of the phonegap-facebook plugin. Everything works fine when the user does not have the native Facebook app installed. However, when they do, nothing happens. When you click login, you are redirected to the native app and asked to confirm permissions. But no response is returned and you are not logged in. When calling:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'id, name, picture' },  function(response) {
        //display friends etc
});
```

the response comes back:

```
{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", "type":OAuthException", "code":2500}
```

All of this works if native app not installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this facebook plugin  its work fine

https://github.com/jimzim/phonegap-facebook-android-sample